# Declaratively defining fragments inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have 5 unique pages of xml that are fairly complex.  I want to put the 5 pages inside a ViewPager.  All of the samples I can find simply put identical contents in each page via code.  I want to declaratively define the xml in the viewpager like the xml pasted below.  But this does not work - the app stops with this xml.

If I can't declaratively define it, then  can I load individual xml pages into the viewpager?  I can find no examples that do this.
thanks,
Gary Blakely

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/flashright" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:scaleType="fitXY">
    </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>       
</fragment>

<fragment >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/flashleft" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:scaleType="fitXY">
    </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>             
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow, you want to declare everything in XML and avoid any programmatic initialization from within your Activity containing the ViewPager.  The only way I can think of doing this would be to define 3 different Fragment classes which reference 3 different xml layouts.  You could then embed them in your above xml, replacing each `<Fragment>` element with `<FragmentX>` `<FragmentY>` `<FragmentZ>` etc.  Personally, I would rather write 3 xml layouts and create a single Fragment implementation that takes a single int argument to designate which layout to load, and then do the small amount of programmatic initialization necessary to make such a solution work.  The rationale being that there is less duplicated code.

EDIT:
Another approach that might more fully address your requirements is to replace your `<Fragment>` tags with `<Layout>` tags and give them id's.  Then in your Activity code, store refs to them, remove them from the View in onCreate() and finally add each of the stored references into programmatically created instances of Fragment which you then add to your ViewPager.  Very ugly but thats the only way I know of to declaratively define everything in XML.  You'll still have the problem that its not clear from the XML that these elements are nested within a ViewPager so personally I don't see the point. ListView and ListFragment operate with the same kind of implicit association though so its not unprecedented.

Comment: it was a bad code pasting job - that xml was inside a viewpager.  I ended up inflating the various xml files in code.  I'm new to Android and used to XAML where we can do just about anything declaratively.